# Twitter.Authorize Won't Show Me Nothing

Tags: android, oauth, twitter, app-inventor

I'm developing a program using App Inventor that will tweet stuff.

I've assigned a button(`btLogin`) to authenticate with Twitter, using `TwitterAPI.Authorize()` and another button to check when it is authorized. If it throws me the even `IsAuthorized` it will display a label saying that. The problem is that when I click on the login button, nothing happens and when I click on the check button nothing happens too. What should I do?

Comment: Please post your code and any stack traces you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're following the full OAuthentication process. An example flow of the process can be seen [here](http://teeky.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/Twitter-oAuth-Diagram.png).